# How to make sure whether my laptop is running on 'Intel 6th Generation' processor or any other ordinary processor?

Tags: laptop, cpu, lenovo-laptop, computer-building

I just bought a **Lenovo laptop** from an authorized multi-brand retail outlet.

I specifically asked the shop representative that I want a laptop which runs on any of the **'Intel 6th Generation'** processor.

So, **she** suggested me the **'Lenovo ideapad 500'** with **FullHD(1920*1080) screen resolution** pre-loaded with **Windows 10 Home Edition** running on **Intel 6th Generation i5 microprocessor**.

Without wasting a moment I bought that laptop as she impressed me more with her persona, her beauty, her talk, her outfits and last but not the least demo of the laptop she shown to me.

Then I come to home and started my laptop. Went to **Control Panel --> System** and got surprised after seeing the below line :

```
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200 CPU @ 2.30 GHz 2.40 GHz
System type : 64-bit Operating System, x64 based processor
```

[image: You can refer the below screen-shot which depicts the system information]

No where I seen the word **'Intel 6th Generation'** processor.

So I got confused and come here for help. Did she make me fool by selling me the laptop with some other ordinary processor or what? Please explain me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The computer will never say "6th generation" The computer will say, as yours does, a processor model, e.g. i5-6200

Then you have to look on the intel site, or wikipedia, to see where that model falls in terms of processor generation.

http://ark.intel.com/products/family/88393/6th-Generation-Intel-Core-i5-Processors

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core

Answer (score 2):

Intel has a page that lists their 6th Generation Core i5 processors:

http://ark.intel.com/products/family/88393/6th-Generation-Intel-Core-i5-Processors

Your processor is listed there, so it is indeed a 6th-generation processor.  Note that the i5-6200 is just an abbreviation for the i5-6200U there is no listed of the "i5-6200" (without the U) on Intel's site.

Comment: U might indicate ULV chips?

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU MODEL SHOWS i5 6200 which is actually the 6th generation i5 cpu.

It has 15w TDP.

No need to worry.

BTW congratulations you have a brand new Laptop.